# FFT Multiple 1d transforms using FFTW

Tags: fortran, fft, fftw

I have a 3-dimensional array U(z,y,x) and I want to perform a complex Fourier transform in z for all values of y and x. I am planning to use the FFTW library. I figured out from the FFTW manual that there is a way to perform multiple 1d transforms at once(mentioned below).

CALL dfftw_plan_many_dft(PLAN, rank, n, howmany, in, inembed, istride, idist, out, onembed, ostride, odist, FFTW_MEASURE)

I don't clearly understand what `inembed` and `outembed` means. Could you provide more insight into this as I am new to Fortran and I am not entirely sure how to use this?

EDIT1: updated the Fortran code

Comment: Yes. I just provided that as for reference. I will update the Fortran version now.

Answer (score 3):

It's described here actually quite well:
http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html

`inembed` and `outembed` allow one to embed the incoming and outgoing data into a larger dataset:

Imagine that you would like to FFT the sub-matrix of `in` denoted by the `O` elements. And possibly outembed the result into the `out` variable's `O` fields.

```
     X X X X X           X X X X X X
     X X X X X           X O O X X X
in = X O O X X     out = X O O X X X
     X O O X X
     X X X X X
```

`inembed` then would be [2, 1] (column-major) and `outmbed` [1, 1]. Then stride would take you from slice to slice / volume to volume etc. Using `stride` and `embed` you tell FFTW, how to find the `O` elements for each sub-data to transform and equally, where to put them in a larger dataset.

Hope this explains it. If you already now the the BLAS interface, you will find that `inembed` and `outembed` correspond to `LDA`, `LDB` of many routines. Of course BLAS routines are limited to matrices, i.e. assume 2 dimensional operations. FFTs you may of course do in as many dimensions as you like.

If you set `inembed` and `outembed` as `NULL`, then FFTW assumes that there are no `X` fields in either input our output respectively.

Comment: I do not understand how [2,1] and [1,1] follow from the pictured matrices.

Comment: `[2,1]` in column-major would mean start with 3rd row, 2nd column. In row-major, `[1,2]` of course, but you were writing fortran, that's why i went with column-manjor. That's the top-left corner of your embedded matrix.

Comment: I see, I was counting from bottom-left. My bad. I always think of the Cartesian space with FFT because of my most-common applications.

Comment: everything starts in top left corner on computers. same applies to mathematica, matlab.

Comment: I know. Physical space, however, does not.