# How to improve performance of the do loop by using openMP?

Tags: performance, loops, fortran, openmp, do-loops

As shown below, this code snippet aims to compute two arrays, i.e. `data_real` and `data_imag`. Their shapes are both 1024*10000. I want to speed up the computation of DO loops by using OpenMP. But I'm an absolute beginner of openMP. I am not very clear how to parallelizing a loop with dependent iterations, such as the statements  `temp2 = dx * temp1(2*i), temp3 = dx * temp1(2*i+1)` of the snippet below. I mean, if there are race conditions in this code snippet.

Is there a way to speed up the do loops as shown below?

**Note**: `Four1` is the subroutine used to perform FFT, `sinc2` is the square of the sinc function.

```
!Declare variables
Real, Allocatable, Dimension(:,:) :: data_complex, data_real, data_imag  
Real, Dimension(0:2*1024-1) :: temp1
Real :: temp2, temp3

!Allocate
Allocate( data_real(0:1024-1,0:10000-1),                    & 
         data_imag(0:1024-1,0:10000-1),                     &            
         data_complex(0:2*1024-1,0:10000-1), STAT=istat1 )

!Initialise 
data_real = 0.0
data_imag = 0.0
data_complex = 0.0
dk = 2*3.14159 / 75.0

!$OMP Parallel num_threads(24) private(i,j,k,temp1,temp2,temp3) shared( dk)
!$OMP Do schedule(dynamic,1) 
  Do j = 0, 10000-1 
    temp1(:) = data_complex(:,j)
    Call Four1(temp1, 1024, 1)                          ! Calling the subroutine 'Four1' to 
                                                        ! perform Fast Fourier Transform
    Do i = 0, 1023
      k = dk * Real(i)
      temp2 = dx * temp1(2*i)          
      temp3 = dx * temp1(2*i+1)        
      data_real(i,j) = temp2 / sinc2( dx * k / 2 )      ! sinc2(x) = sin(x) / x
      data_imag(i,j) = temp3 / sinc2( dx * k / 2 )          
    End Do 
  End Do
!$OMP End Do nowait
!$OMP End Parallel
! --------------------------------------------------------------- !
! ----------------------------------------------------------------!
Subroutine Four1(data_complex, nn, isign)

    Integer, Intent(in) :: nn
    Integer, Intent(in) :: isign
    Real, Intent(inout), Dimension(2*nn) :: data_complex
    Integer :: i, istep, j, m, mmax, n
    Real :: tempi, tempr
    Real(8) :: theta, wi, wpi, wpr, wr, wtemp
    ! ---------------------------------------------------------
    n=2*nn
    j=1
    Do i=1,n,2
      If(j>i) then
        tempr=data_complex(j)
        tempi=data_complex(j+1)
        data_complex(j)=data_complex(i)
        data_complex(j+1)=data_complex(i+1)
        data_complex(i)=tempr
        data_complex(i+1)=tempi
      endif
      m=n/2

      Do while ( (m>=2).and.(j>m) )
        j=j-m
        m=m/2
      End do

      j=j+m
    EndDo
    
    mmax=2
    Do while ( n > mmax )
       istep=2*mmax
       theta=(2*pi)/(isign*mmax)
       wpr=-2.0d0*sin(0.5d0*theta)**2
       wpi=sin(theta)
       wr=1.0d0
       wi=0.0d0
       Do m=1,mmax,2
         Do i=m,n,istep
           j=i+mmax
           tempr=Real(wr)*data_complex(j)-Real(wi)*data_complex(j+1)
           tempi=Real(wr)*data_complex(j+1)+Real(wi)*data_complex(j)
           data_complex(j)=data_complex(i)-tempr
           data_complex(j+1)=data_complex(i+1)-tempi
           data_complex(i)=data_complex(i)+tempr
           data_complex(i+1)=data_complex(i+1)+tempi
         End Do
         wtemp=wr
         wr=wr*wpr-wi*wpi+wr
         wi=wi*wpr+wtemp*wpi+wi
       End Do
       mmax=istep
     End Do

  End Subroutine Four1
  ! ------------------------------------------------------------ !
  ! ------------------------------------------------------------ !

  Real Function sinc2 ( x )
    !
    ! Define the square of sinc function
    !
    Real, Intent(in) :: x
    
    If ( abs(x) < 1.e-16 ) then
    ! be careful with comparison to real numbers because of rounding errors
    ! better: if (abs(x).lt.1.e-16) thensinc=1.
      sinc2 = 1.0
    Else 
      sinc2 = ( sin(x)/x )**2
    End If
  
  End Function sinc2
```

Comment: You could use sections or tasks to wait for the dependant calculation to finish while others execute in parallel.

Comment: @Isma Could you provide more details?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions to get more attention from Fortran experts. Your question is not specific to the old Fortran 95.

Comment: A couple of suggestions which I can't test because you don't provide a complete program: First I would use a good FFT library such as FFTW rather than what I suspect are the NR routines, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61735200/fft-multiple-1d-transforms-using-fftw might help. Second while your OpenMP looks fine (and if I didn't use a library close to how I would do it) are you sure that your hardware efficiently supports 24 threads? I would rather not hardwire in the number of threads, but instead use OMP_NUM_THREADS and see how the time varies with its value.

Comment: @IanBush My machine has 24 cores

Comment: I just mention that dx is not defined in your code while you are using it in sinc2 function. For the parallelization, it is difficult to do something more efficient. Probably passing dk and dx as firstprivate might give a slightly better solution.